# Ajax CollapsiblePanelExtender Keep state on Postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a gridview. Inside I have a CollapsiblePanelExtender that contains buttons. When I press a button this causes a post back and the CollapsiblePanelExtender closes. I am trying to compose a solution that will keep the CollapsiblePanelExtender open after the post back.
This is what I have attempted so far:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
   var objExtender;                
   var retval="";               

   if (document.getElementById(GridView1)) {
      retval = document.getElementById(GridView1);
   }
   var CollapsiblePanelExtender1 = retval.getElementsByTagName("CollapsiblePanelExtender1");

   if(CollapsiblePanelExtender1.get_Collapsed()) {
      CollapsiblePanelExtender1.set_Collapsed(true);
   }
   else {
      CollapsiblePanelExtender1.set_Collapsed(false);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically CollapsiblePanelExtender keeps it's state during postbacks. But during post back I suppose that you perform databind (I guess you have). During databinding all controls are recreated and that's why they are loose their internal states.

To fix your issue I can advice to save state of the CollapsiblePanelExtender before performing databinding and then restore this state. This can be done on server side. This will also help to avoid flicker of the UI if you have animation enabled.

So, to get state of the CollapsiblePanelExtender you can simply to remember it's client state value. Then you will able to restore this value. For example this is code which can be used to expand/collapse CollapsiblePanelExtender on server side:

```
// To collapse panel.
this.CollapsiblePanelExtender1.ClientState = "true";

// To Expand panel.
this.CollapsiblePanelExtender1.ClientState = "false";
```

If you still want to collapse/expand CollapsiblePanelExtender on client side than you need code similar to this:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function() {
    var extender = $find('<%= this.CollapsiblePanelExtender1.ClientID  %>');

    extender.expandPanel();

    extender.collapsePanel();
});
```

*EDIT*
This doesn't help because you try to restore state in the click handler. When you call databind of the grid view control, rows are not recreated immediately. So, if you want to set (restore) state of the collapsible extender control it is better to do in RowCreated event handler of your grid.

For example you can use code similar to this:

```
    protected void GridView_OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && SomeValueToIdentifyThatThisPanelShouldBeExpanded)
        {
            CollapsiblePanelExtender extender =
                e.Row.FindControl("CollapsiblePanelExtender1") as CollapsiblePanelExtender;
            extender.ClientState = "false";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried what you suggest but it’s not working. As I told you the collapsible panel extender is inside on a gridview template. So to find it I have to use findcontrol. I am adding the ajax control toolkit to my context, and I am writing the code to find the collapsible panel. After that I set  CollapsiblePanelExtender1. ClientState = "false"  at the end of the onclick function I have. Unfortunately the collapsible panel is closed again after the post back

Comment: @focus I updated my answer. Please see edit section.

Comment: This opens the expandable panel on all rows. I want to open the expandable panel on the specific row of the gridview. With your solution opens on all rows.

Comment: Yes, but you simply need to add logic to identify what collapsible panel extender state should be restored (and this can be done by different ways and depends on your domain).

Comment: I have added a Viewstate that has  value True when the collapsible panel should be opened, this is clear. But how can distinct the collapsible panel that needs to be open? If all rows has open panels it is not very helpfull. Imagine 100 records to have open collapsible panels.

Answer (score 1):

I actually use these on my blog because asp.net lets me use the collapsible panel drag and drop with a repeater control.

**The trick is to ajax in the content when you open the panel.**  You could easily jquery in the content to insert a page or ajax in from a webservice.

This is a sample of the collapsible panel with ajaxed content.  The panels are loaded by a webservice.  Click to expand the panels.

http://gosylvester.com/blog.aspx?id=39

Comment: Please can you be more specific?The are a lot of information on the link that you have assign me. My problem is that the collapsible panel is inside the gridview row. when i expand i see details about the record and i can edit from the textboxes of the row. The problem is that when i press for example save button, occurs post back and the collapsible panel closes. So now the user should try to find again the record that he was and re expand the collapsible panel.

Comment: It's an example a sample.  The trick is to never post back from your colapsible panel.  Just get the content when it opens.  When the panel closes the content will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the SuppressPostBack="True" on the collapsible panel extender